# Map commands to methods

Tags: c#

I have a command line app where I map commands to methods, using a dictionary from the one-letter command to the name of the method (as a string).  I can use this method both to invoke it and also to tell the user the list of available commands, like so:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> commands =
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"u", "DestroyUniverse"},
        {"g", "DestroyGalaxy"},
        {"p", "DestroyPlanet"},
        {"t", "TimeTravel"}
    };

public void DestroyUniverse(Stack<string> argStack)
{
     // destroy the universe according to the options in argStack
     // ...
}

public void DestroyGalaxy(Stack<string> argStack)
{
     // destroy the galaxy according to the options in argStack
     // ...
}

// ... other command methods

public void Run(Stack<string> argStack)
{
    var cmd = argStack.Next();
    string methodName;

    // if no command given, or command is not found, tell
    // user the list of available commands

    if (cmd == null || !commands.TryGetValue(cmd, out methodName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Available Commands:{0}{1}", 
            Environment.NewLine, 
            string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            commands.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key)
                    .Select(kv => string.Format("{0} - {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value))));

        Environment.ExitCode = 1;
        return;
    }

    // command is valid, call the method

    GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(this, new object[] {argStack});
}
```

This is working fine, except I don't like that I'm using strings as the value in the dictionary. There is thus no compiler support for making sure there is a method for every string. I'd rather use "methods" somehow, but still have access to the name of the method, for the part where I list the commands.  Is there anything like that available?

Comment: Maybe you could create an interface / abstract class called `Command` and the command has a `Name` property and a method called `Execute`.  Interestingly enough, this is the command pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern, you would then have different derivatives for each type of "command"

Comment: why don't you use `Enum` and access it based on the (Integer) ordinal of that.. is that a possibility..?

Comment: An action delegate does not give me access to a method name for the command listing

Comment: @Mathew, how would I get a list of commands for the command listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doesn't this work?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Run(new Stack<string>(args.Reverse()));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<Stack<string>>> commands;

    public Program() {
        commands =
            new Dictionary<string, Action<Stack<string>>>
            {
                {"u", DestroyUniverse },
                {"g", DestroyGalaxy },
                {"p", DestroyPlanet },
                {"t", TimeTravel }       
            };
     }

    public void DestroyUniverse(Stack<string> argStack)
    {
        // destroy the universe according to the options in argStack
        // ...
    }

    public void DestroyGalaxy(Stack<string> argStack)
    {
        // destroy the galaxy according to the options in argStack
        // ...
    }

    private string Next(Stack<string argStack)
    {
        // wish this was a method of Stack<T>
        return argStack.Any() ? argStack.Pop() : null;
    }

    public void Run(Stack<string> argStack)
    {
        var cmd = Next(argStack);

        Action<Stack<string>> action = null;

        // if no command given, or command is not found, tell
        // user the list of available commands
        if (cmd == null || !commands.TryGetValue(cmd, out action))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Available Commands:{0}{1}",
                Environment.NewLine,
                string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                    commands.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key)
                        .Select(kv => string.Format("{0} - {1}",
                             kv.Key, kv.Value.Method.Name))));
            Environment.ExitCode = 1;
            return;
        }

        // command is valid, call the method
        action(argStack);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't have the extension method(?) for the stack so i just set that to null in the Run as the example code is not complete. But that should list the method names properly when cmd = null.

Comment: changed "Add" calls to Dictionary initialization; removed check for action == null (not necessary since TryGetValue returned true)

Comment: also initialized cmd from argStack

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection. Get a MethodInfo of all the methods you're intrested in and put them in the dictionary. Later then you can invoke one of them. If you need the name of the method as string, you can get it also from the MethodInfo.